# Data loss in converting char array to string

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

I am using two different way for converting `char array` to `string` but both of them returns 4 as `length` of string while the char size is 16:

```
char chr[16] = { 0x0E,0x1F,0xBA,0x0E,0x00,0xB4,0x09,0xCD,0x21,0xB8,0x01,0x4C,0xCD,0x21,0x57,0x69 };

const string str(chr); // First try
string str2 = static_cast<string>(chr); // Second try

cout << sizeof chr << endl; // size of the char
cout << "Converted: " << str << " Size: " << str.length() << endl; // length of converted char
cout << "Converted: " << str2 << " Size: " << str2.length() << endl; // length of converted char
```

What is the reason of this data loss? And what is the fix?

Comment: If you want an array of chars rather than a piece of text, consider `std::vector<char>`. Probably even better would be `std::vector<std::int8_t>` or `std::vector<std::uint8_t>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\0` are considered as terminating the string
and in

```
char chr[16] = { 0x0E,0x1F,0xBA,0x0E,0x00,0xB4,0x09,0xCD,0x21,0xB8,0x01,0x4C,0xCD,0x21,0x57,0x69 };
```

your fifth character is a `\0`.

So string is build only with the first 4 characters.

You can fix it by using the constructor from string where you can specify the size.
replace `const string str(chr);` by `const string str(chr, 16);`

also `0xB4`, `0xCD` and `0xB8` don't fit in an char as they are above 128

Comment: Nice find, I was looking at this blankly feeling like an idiot

Comment: Should i use unsigned char for those characters?

Comment: @AidenStewart the numbers in an `unsigned char` would fit but `std::string` expect `char`

Comment: As you have a true array, you could replace the magic number 16 with `sizeof(chr)`. If you later change the size, you will have to change it in one single place...